# Wordpress theme, custm post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I create a custom post with this code, also a read more button. this post showing successfully on welcome template. But when i click on read more button, then showing nothing found!!. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

[the code is here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101570127/code.png)

Comment: What is the URL that the excerpt is linking to ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

<div class="right_pnl_data">
                  <h1>Regional Race Calendar</h1>
                    <?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => 4 );
                    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
                    $a= get_the_date();
                    ?> 
                      <strong><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></strong><br />
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: What happens while you click on the excerpt link?

Comment: i want this post open in a new page. not like blog post.

please click the link below to see the template
http://morshed.byethost16.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

please use below code:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

thanks.